# Haskell Precedence: Lambda and operator

Tags: haskell, grammar, operator-precedence

I found precedence and associativity is a big obstacle for me to understand what the grammar is trying to express at first glance to haskell code.

For example,

```
blockyPlain :: Monad m => m t -> m t1 -> m (t, t1)
blockyPlain xs ys = xs >>= \x -> ys >>= \y -> return (x, y)
```

By experiment, I finally got it means,

```
blockyPlain xs ys = xs >>= (\x -> (ys >>= (\y -> return (x, y))))
```

instead of

```
blockyPlain xs ys = xs >>= (\x -> ys) >>= (\y -> return (x, y))
```

Which works as:

```
*Main> blockyPlain [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
[(1,4),(1,5),(1,6),(2,4),(2,5),(2,6),(3,4),(3,5),(3,6)]
```

I can get info from ghci for (>>=) as an operator, (infixl 1 >>=).

But there's no information for -> since it's not an operator.

Could someone of you guys give some reference to make this grammar thing easier to grasp?

Comment: The [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-220003) is the definitive reference for Haskell syntax, though perhaps a BNF grammar is a bit low-level for the question you're asking...?

Comment: I too struggle with precedence in Haskell and knowing when parens are appropriate and when they are superfluous. Any tutorials or guides other than the link above are welcomed.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The rule for lambdas is pretty simple: the body of the lambda extends as far to the right as possible without hitting an unbalanced parenthesis.

```
f (\x -> foo (bar baz) *** quux >>= quuxbar)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                       body
```

Comment: Which means it applies last.  That is, (->) has a lower precedence then any other operator.  I believe the same is true of `do` and (<-) as well they extend as far right as possible, apply last, and have a lower precedence then any operator.

Comment: I really don't like the terms "first" and "last" for precendence -- I think it conflates grouping with evaluation order. It's something I run up against in math teaching.  I like "tight" and "loose", thinking of the operators as holding on to their operands.  Anyway, `->` isn't really an infix operator, since it does not connect two terms; rather, lambda is a syntactic form for an expression.  That's why I didn't answer in terms of operators.

Comment: Both points well taken. "First" and "last" are the phrases used in most k-12 (and not a few undergrad) math curricula when talking about order of operations. My attempt was to apply those commonly used (though less accurate) terms to your very fine answer.

Answer (score 7):

A good rule of thumb seems to be that you can never make a custom operator that has precedence over built in syntactic constructs. For instance consider this example:

```
if b then f *** x else f *** y
```

Regardless of the associativity of `***`, no one would expect it to binds as:

```
(if b then f *** x else f) *** y
```

There aren't a lot of syntactic constructs in Haskell (`do` and `case` are a little special because of layout syntax) but `let` can be used as another example:

```
(let x = y in y *** x) /= ((let x = y in y) *** x)
```