# Rewrite a monad computation in prefix notation

Tags: haskell, infix-notation

I'm trying to figure out how to rewrite a monadic computation with prefix notation (not for real practical goals, just for research), but the problem that one lambda doesn't see another one's parameter

so given a working example

```
*Main> [1, 3, 4] >>= \x -> [x + 1, x - 1] >>= \y -> return (y*x)
[2,0,12,6,20,12]
```

the rewritten one shows the error on not seeing the parameter of other lambda

```
*Main> (>>=) ( (>>=)  [1, 3, 4] (\x -> [x + 1, x - 1]) ) (\y -> return (y*x))
<interactive>:133:68: Not in scope: `x'
```

but if I make the last one not using it (by replacing x with y), the computation starts working

```
*Main> (>>=) ( (>>=)  [1, 3, 4] (\x -> [x + 1, x - 1]) ) (\y -> return (y*y))
[4,0,16,4,25,9]
```

So does full rewriting in prefix notation technically possible? Or this property of accessing other lambdas parameters is exclusive to the infix notation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you got the precedences slightly wrong, see also [Haskell Precedence: Lambda and operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237076/haskell-precedence-lambda-and-operator)

The body of a lambda-expression extends as far to the right as possible. Then your example is parenthesized as follows:

```
[1, 3, 4] >>= (\x -> [x + 1, x - 1] >>= (\y -> return (y*x)))
```

Bringing it into prefix form results in

```
(>>=) [1, 3, 4] (\x -> (>>=) [x + 1, x - 1] (\y -> return (y*x)))
```

Now `x` is visible inside the body of `\y -> ...`.

Comment: Seems like infix notation containing lambdas (if inference allows them in the operators context) should inject expressions inside the bodies of lambdas, right? Looks natural in your explanation, but I never met this in tutorials.

Comment: @Maksee Your question isn't very clear to me. What do you think is being injected where?